# Panels Pane Content Added - Stacked, need Inline

Tags: panels, theming

Hi I'm developing an Intranet in Open Atrium - Drupal 7. The distribution is heavy on Panels, so I am developing the Portal with them. However I have a Pane for one of the Panels and I want to upload 4/5 separate blocks into it. However the default behaviour is everything is stacked in the pane, and I would like to be able to control it so I can lay things out side by side, is there a way to do this within the Drupal System. At present I am using Negative Relative Positioning to move things where I want them. Then specifying a height for the body to get rid of the negative space it leaves - not ideal. I can't use Negative Margins because the company where the Intranet is uses a lot of IE7 and IE7 doesn't recognise negative margins.

Answer (score 0):

You could use custom panel layouts (use the builder option) and create the regions you want with the size and position you want.

Comment: Awesome thanks, does that work with Panopoly?

Comment: Probably.  A judicious use of mini panels would address any places where the builder isn't an option.